# проблема с настройкой smtp через gmail

Tags: python, smtp, gmail

```
 File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/common/djangoapps/student/views.py", line 1800, in create_account_with_params
user.email_user(subject, message, from_address)
 File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 433, in email_user
send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email], **kwargs)
 File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 62, in send_mail
return mail.send()
 File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 303, in send
return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
 File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 100, in send_messages
new_conn_created = self.open()
 File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 58, in open
self.connection = connection_class(self.host, self.port, **connection_params)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 256, in __init__
(code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 316, in connect
self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 291, in _get_socket
return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 557, in create_connection
for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

пользовались ЕС2 от амазон и все было ок, как только перешли на впс, то вот такая лажа началась. Логин\пароль\порт\ip правильные на 110%

Comment: опечатки в хосте нет? Что `socket.getaddrinfo('smtp.gmail.com', 587)` возвращает?

Comment: была проблема в том, что в консоли был закрыт доступ.

Comment: если вы думаете, что нашли решение, то опубликуйте его как свой ответ -- [это явно приветствуется.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)